# how to create several select drop down listbox using php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I am new to php, I would like to generate the same select drop down list box. 
This is the code I have, but it only works for the first drop down, not for the second one...

This is the code I am using without any success :

```html
<?php 
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
      {  
           $output .= '  
                <tr>  
                     <td>'.$row["id"].'</td>  
          <td class="last_name"  >
      <select id="t1"><option>'.$row["t1"].'</option>';   
        while($rowcode=mysqli_fetch_array($resulttasks))
         { $output .= '<option value="'.$rowcode["id"].'">'.$rowcode["code"].'</option>' ; }
        $output .='</select>
      </td>  
      <td class="last_name"  >
      <select id="t2"><option>'.$row["t2"].'</option>';   
        while($rowcode=mysqli_fetch_array($resulttasks))
         { $output .= '<option value="'.$rowcode["id"].'">'.$rowcode["code"].'</option>'; }
        $output .='</select>
      </td>  
   </tr>';
?>
```

Thanks in advance for the help !

Comment: `id="t1"` ID will not repeat use different IDs or use class here.

Comment: before the second loop of "t2", try putting `mysqli_data_seek($resulttasks,0);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Duplicate identifiers is not the issue, before the second loop of "t2" select, try putting `mysqli_data_seek($resulttasks,0);`

**Explanation:**
duplicate identifiers are only for DOM and it has nothing to do with parsing HTML in PHP. If you guys notice, he is using the same result set two times, PHP does not run another loop on same data once process already. So, we have to reset to 0th row if we want to run another loop on the same result set.

Comment: Thanks a lot !
can you tell me why I have to do this ?

Comment: You can check my comment above in the first answer, and if my solution works for you then do some favor :).

Answer (score 0):

The `id` attribute must be unique, replace the duplicate ones by common classes :

```
<select id="t1">
```

Must be :

```
<select class="t1">
```

So when you loop through the `$result` you'll not generate duplicate identifiers.

Comment: I think it's already unique 
 <select id="t1">  &  <select id="t2">
or am i mistaken ?

Comment: @drb, u are using loop

Comment: Inside a foreach, it will be duplicated if the `foreach` will loop 3 times we'll end up with 3 duplicate id's.

Comment: duplicate identifiers are only for DOM and it has nothing to do with parsing HTML in PHP. If you guys notice, he is using the same result set two times, PHP does not run another loop on same data once process already. So, we have to reset to 0th row if we want to run another loop on the same result set.

Comment: Good catch @DanishHakimKhan +1

Answer (score 0):

hope this helps you
change your id with loop
example

```
$index = 1;
    for($i = 0; $i < $count_array; $i ++) {
        echo '<select id="t1' . $index . '"></select>';
        $index ++;
    }
```